# SQLiteOpenHelper close() was never explicitly called

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

Android 2.3.3

I have two activities in my application that access the database. Whenever I change the orientation of the mobile, i get the following errors in logcat, though the program does work. I understand from the errors that I have to call `close()` and close the database and cursors. But where do i put it exactly.

Will closing the database and cursors in `onDestroy()` of the activity, solves the issue?

```
    Database pm;
        Cursor c;

    @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
          pm.close();
          c.close();
          // Any other cursors that are used...

            super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Here is the logcat trace incase needed...

```
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602): close() was never explicitly called on database 'portfolio' 
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1849)
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:822)
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:856)
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:849)
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602):    at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:553)
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602):    at com.xx.xxx.Database.<init>(Database.java:21)
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602):    at com.xx.xxx.Brokerage_Settings.onCreate(Brokerage_Settings.java:118)
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
02-16 22:37:50.419: E/Database(602):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is the best practise to close the database and cursor objects?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Updated the question with logcat trace..

Comment: @VamsiChalla `onPause()` is the better place.

Comment: I would generally open and close the db and cursor within the function that you use it. Therefore, by the time you hit onDestroy everything should already be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call close in onPause(). When you change orientation of mobile your app changes state and you are supposed to close database/cursor object before the super.onPause() is called by android system. Call close in onPause method before the command super.onPause().